# Chrome devtools filesystem/workspace problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I did a stupid thing. In the devtools (Chrome 69 on macOS Sierra 10.12) under "Sources > Filesystem > Add folder to workspace", I accidentally tried to add my system root (/) as a folder.

Now whenever I open the devtools, Chrome and mtmfs (Mobile Time Machine file system daemon) goes to 100% CPU.

The folder list is empty, so is the list in "Settings > Workspaces".

Can I fix this situation somehow without deleting my current profile? (I like my current profile...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that "Restore defaults and reload" at the bottom of Settings > Preferences would clear this.

If that doesn't work, you could do surgery on your preferences with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Quit Chrome, then:

```bash
cd /path/to/Chrome/Default
mv Preferences Preferences.bak
jq 'del(.devtools.file_system_paths)' <Preferences.bak >Preferences
```

Comment: Thank you, Restore Defaults did not work, somehow and I had already searched the profile folder for a clue, but did not find anything. jq was not necessary, a simple text editor did the trick.